# wp7 add alarm entry

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, interop, alarm

Is there a way to programmatically add an alarm entry from the app I am creating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently the SDK doesn't offer any capabilities to interact with systems applications like the Alarms app from a third-party application. I am sure there is a native hook for this (considering the way apps interact internally), but it's not publicly available right now.

Comment: Do you know when they might allow this to happen?  Are there any sites out there that specialize in these types of questions (i.e. rumor sites, or WP7 Programmer sites)?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any plans on releasing functionality like this. Given the fact that it's not official, even if you find a hook to do this, you will not be able to get your app approved for the WP Marketplace. On a sidenote, you should follow guys like Chris Walshie (http://blog.walshie.me/) - he tries to dig deeper in the WP7 platform and so far has found some interesting things.